# vim: how to record norm commands?

Tags: vim, macro

I edit and correct a lot of identical files

using those commands

```
:%norm f^ID
:%s/\s\+$//
:%norm A,
:%norm GG$x
```

I also used the macro mode

```
qa
```

for record macro a

and

```
@a
```

to execute

But for some strange reason
or probably my error
it applied only some commands

My question is: is possible to save
those command in a script
and use

```
 vim -N -u NONE -n -c "set nomore" -S script.vi file.txt
```

Of course the syntax

```
:%norm f^ID
:%s/\s\+$//
:%norm A,
:%norm GG$x
```

Used in a script give me a error

Vim is 7.4 on slackware 14.2

Comment: try `-s ...` and add a `:x` in the end. There is several options for sourcing files: `-S ex-commands`  (no ":") or `-s vim-commands`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not exactly what you asked, but you can create vim scripts with your content. Lets start with a simple case:

```
$ cat noendspaces
#!/usr/bin/vim -s
:%s/ *$//
:r ! echo "\#last changed by $USER in :" `date`
:x
```

and then...

```
$ chmod 755 noendspaces
$ for a in file*.txt 
  do
    ./noendspaces $a
  done
```

Comment: The syntax is ok,but doesn't work with norm commands,with other commands works but doesn't solve my problem

Comment: @elbarna, I added a `:%norm A,` to my script and it worked. Could you detail the  "doesn't work with norm commands"

Comment: I have tried the script with my file and it doesn't work,use the same commands one by one on vim work

Comment: @elbarna, strange! 1) could you please check `which vim`? 2) please make a small test with: line1=`#!/usr/bin/vim -s`, line 2=`:%norm A,` and line 3=`:x` and check if it adds ","

Comment: vim 7.4 on Slackware 14.2